# Rails: What is the convention for controllers with many words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

Say I have the model CourseGroup. What would be the controller's name?

Comment: It sounds as though the way you're designing it may lead to problems down the line, not in line with DRY.  If you're planning on having many groups, I would strongly urge you away from having a controller per group.  Instead, each group should have a separate name.

Comment: I have the model 'Course', which has its own controller. And then I have the model CourseGroup which has_many Courses. I will search in a thesaurus for a proper word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The controller name would be `course_groups_controller`.

http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7

To find the name for any model, you can open up a rails console and do `"ModelName".tableize`.  Then just add "_controller" to the end.  This would result in `model_names_controller`.

Comment: What about the controller class name?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to find out the naming conventions: Just create a throw-away Rails app in a temp directory, with a scaffolded model:

```
rails blog
cd blog
./script/generate scaffold post subject:string content:text
```

You can then browse through the files and directories to see how things are named. I like to keep one of these around just to refer to from time to time. And by the way, running the generators without any parameters gives help output which includes examples of naming conventions:

```
./script/generate scaffold
```